# Download Plotly HTML From Databricks

Tags: python, plotly, databricks

I have a plotly figure that I want to download the HTML for.
When I try:

```
fig.to_html()
```

It will only output some of the HTML string and ends with this:

```
*** WARNING: skipped 3421789 bytes of output ***
```

Does anyone know how I can force databricks to show all of the HTML or copy it to my clipboard?

Comment: Ever found an answer to this? I have the same problem...

Comment: Unfortunately no. My super hacky workaround was to get the HTML as a string object and then split it into chunks: html_out[:5000] and html_out[5000:] 

Not a great solution at all, but it worked in the moment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That works, but as you say, super hacky... I will see whether I can find a different method.

Answer (score 1):

Still a bit hacky, but the following should work to save and download a file from Databricks containing the html:

Assuming you have a plotly figure object and are working in a databricks notebook:

1. Create an html string and assign a variable to it:

```
    html_string = fig.to_html()
```

2. Save to the databricks filesystem using dbutils:

```
   dbutils.fs.put("/FileStore/my_html_file.html", html_string)
```

3. Download the html string by navigating in a browser to:
   https://<databricks-instance>/files/my_html_file.html

Note:

- The databricks instance is usually something like <some_letters>-<some_numbers>.databricks.net
- If you're within an organisation (i.e. your databricks URLs typically end in "?o=<organisation_id>"), then you may need to add this to the end of the URL in step 3.